# jmeter number of threads as variables

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

My performance test requires orthogonal combination of **thread numbers** and **data**. For example, I want to test
`/path_1` under `1, 2, ... n` threads, then
`/path_2` under `1, 2, ... n` threads, then
`/path_n` under `1, 2, ... n` threads.
Note I want run different threads for same path first, then another path.

The simplest solution would be a jmeter plan with `thread_count` and `path` as properties, then launch jmeter offering different properties.
such as

```bash
jmeter.sh ... -Jthread_count=1 -Jpath='/path_1' 
jmeter.sh ... -Jthread_count=2 -Jpath='/path_1' 
jmeter.sh ... -Jthread_count=1 -Jpath='/path_2' 
jmeter.sh ... -Jthread_count=2 -Jpath='/path_2'
```

But I want to make most use of jmeter's built in mechanism. Idealy I only have to configure my threads and paths list somewhere, either in files or as json in some scripts, and Jmeter will ramp up threads and paths combination execution for me.

I did two experiments.

- experiment 1: csv data set config
  Add a csv config like following

```
thread_count,voice
1,path_1
2,path_1
1,path_2
2,path_2
```

then add thread group, specifying `number of threads` = `${thread_count}`

But not work, even not run at all. and properties like `sharing mode` in csv config seems to indicate it can not be used to control threads.

- experiment 2: foreach controller

Under *thread group*, add a *JSR223 Sampler*, code like this:

```
vars.put("thread_count_1","1");
vars.put("thread_count_2","2");
vars.put("path_1","path_1");
vars.put("path_2","path_2");
```

add *foreach controller*, export `thread_count` variable, then add a nested *foreach controller*, export `path` variable.
Still not work, the foreach controller exported variable cannot control number of threads.

Could any one suggest how to use jemter's built in mechanism to accomplish my test threads arrangement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot use CSV Data Set Config to control the number of threads in **current** thread group because the Thread Group is initialized [**before**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) the CSV Data Set Config is evaluated
2. ForEach Controller might be a viable option assuming that you:

   - Put it in the [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)
   - Convert JMeter Variables into JMeter Properties to wit:

     ```
     props.put("thread_count_1","1");
     props.put("path_1","path_1");
     ```

   and then use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to read the properties values in the Thread Group of your choice
3. You might want to consider the option of [kicking off threads from the JSR23 Test Elements directly](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/AbstractThreadGroup.html#addNewThread(int,org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine)) like:

   ```
   ctx.getThreadGroup().addNewThread(0,ctx.getEngine())
   ```

Comment: i just tried the 2nd option. in setup, add jsr223 with `props.put("threads","3");` then in thread group set number as `${__P(threads)} `. but thread not run at all. anything wrong?

Comment: I have no idea if "anything wrong", for me it [works just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Robou.gif). Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries and ensure that your `threads` property has the anticipated value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)

Comment: thanks for your quick response. could you have a look at my plan [file](https://github.com/LeiYangGH/jmeter-thread-number-variable/blob/master/notworking.jmx)? i was doing exactly what you said(debug sampler, view tree...)

Comment: i found my issue: there's a space after `${__P(threads)} `! just wierd behaviour. by the way, though now i can set thread number as property. i don't know how to specify threads in for-each controller. can you update answer for it?

Comment: Try using `${__P(threads,)}` in the Thread Group.  Alternatively use [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function like `${__groovy(props.get('threads'),)}` If you're not certain regarding proper function syntax - use [Functions Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper). More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for a way to set the Threadgroup count - then you should use property function instead of variable function.

[image]

Then pass the variable in threadgroup element like the below

[image]

[image]

Then you can overrirde the value for the variable using -J option such as `-Jthreadgroup1=1 Jthreadgroup1=2 Jthreadgroup1=3`

Comment: your code seems to be `The simplest solution` in my question. i cannot open the images due to network restrictions.

Comment: Okay, I have added 3 images 
1. User defined variables
      I have created 3 variable in this component (which you can do in testplan itself - no need to add a separate component)
      In the name field provide a name for the variable e.g, ThreadGroup1 and in the value field provide the prop function ${__P(threadgroup1, 1)} 
      
2. Threadgroups 
     Just pass the variable ${ThreadGroup1} in the Number of Threads field

Comment: i want the thread number automatically increase, i thought your method only start a fixed number of theads.